# Do I need to optimize a WEBP file after exporting it?

Tags: image, optimization, compression, webp

We all know JPEG, PNG and other files should be optimized before deploy using tools like ImageOptim, smushit, kraken etc.

Do we need to do the same for webp images? I mean, is webp capable os storing useless bits like JPEG metadata or anything? Or is webp "naturally optimized"?

If there is a need to optimize WEBP, is there a tool to do this? I tried the classic ones (like ImageOptim and kraken) but they reject my image.

I'm creating my WEBP file exporting a JPEG as WEBP in Pixelmator, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

There are no image optimizers for WebP that I know. I am guessing that we could shave off 5 % of bytes in WebP lossless by applying a Zopfli-like approach, and much much more by applying a near lossless approach within the lossless decoding.